# asp.net mvc outputcache VaryByContentEncoding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Could someone help to explain what is the use of OutputCache VaryByContentEncoding, or better to give an example about its usage.

I know that is relate to the encoding compression. Will it cache different response based on the specific compression scheme ?  I search online, but couldn't find much details about this attributes.

Comment: Found this: https://dotnettrace.net/2013/10/04/output-caching-in-mvc-4-explained/
but I tryed VaryByContentEncoding = "gzip;deflate" and VaryByContentEncoding = "gzip;deflate;compress" and still getting Vary=*

Answer (score 0):

There is now a help doc here with an example that explains how the output is retrieved from the cache or generated depending which headers are present in the request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcachepolicy.varybycontentencodings?view=netframework-4.8

Can also add as an attribute to a method like so:

```
        [OutputCache(Duration = 3600,
            Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server,
            VaryByParam = "id;page",
            VaryByContentEncoding = "gzip, deflate, br, compress"
        )]
        [HttpGet]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Post(int id)
        {
           ...
        }
```

Note: I have `VaryByContentEncoding = "gzip, deflate, br, compress"`
This is in .Net 4.6

Despite the docs it appears that using a semicolon delimited list does not work as expected, at least with the attribute. I've not tried in the markup.

With the setting as above I can send a request with the following 'Accept-Encoding' header values and will get back a cached response with 'Content-Encoding: gzip' , at least from IIS Express.

- accept-encoding: gzip
- accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
- accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
- accept-encoding: deflate, br, gzip

If semi-colon delimited list is used for the setting in the **attribute** then the response is never cached. This **does not** appear to work:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600,
            Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server,
            VaryByParam = "id;page",
            VaryByContentEncoding = "gzip;deflate;br;compress"
     )]
```

Sending an unsupported accept-encoding will return the uncompressed but still cached response as expected.

- accept-encoding: br

Note: the VaryByParam value does work if semi colon delmited as expected.